# use itemrenderer in bar charts in flex

Tags: actionscript, flex3, flex4

I need to use the item renderer in Barchart. but there is no itemRenderer property in barChart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an itemrenderer for the Barchart but there is an itemrenderer for the **BarSeries** property of a barchart.  Basically it allows you to have a renderer for each dataset.